# Exception thrown upon assigning of custom page event to PdfCopy

Tags: c#, exception, itext

I am currently trying to iterate over an existing PDF and stamp each page with some footer text using the `OnPageEnd` event as detailed in the iText documentation, [Chapter 5: Table, cell, and page events](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#225-moviecountries1.java).

When I assign my new custom event class to the PdfCopy instance, I receive this exception:

> "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" at
>   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy.set_PageEvent(IPdfPageEvent value)

Below is the code I have written to preform the operation:

```
PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(file.Value);
int pages = pdf.NumberOfPages;

pdf.SelectPages(string.Format("0 - {0}", pages));
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, stream) { PageEvent = new PdfFooterStamp() };

    doc.Open();
    for (int x = 0, y = pages; x < y; x++)
    {
        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdf, x + 1));
    }

    doc.Close();
    copy.Flush();
    copy.Close();

    collection[file.Key] = stream.ToArray();
}
```

And this is my custom event class definition:

```
public class PdfFooterStamp : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        Rectangle rect = writer.PageSize;
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent,
            Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("PERSONALISED DOCUMENT"),
                (rect.Left + rect.Right) / 2, rect.Bottom - 18, 0);
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
    }
}
```

Is there anyone that might have an idea as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: `PdfPageEventHelper` and `PdfCopy` are mutually exclusive. You can't define a page event when using `PdfCopy`.

Comment: So I must find an alternative method to copy the PDF pages using `PdfWriter`?

Comment: I wouldn't use `PdfWriter` because `PdfWriter` throws away all interactivity. You can keep on using `PdfCopy` and use `PageStamp` to add the text to each page that is added. Or you can create the PDF *in two passes*: first create the concatenated PDF in memory with `PdfCopy`; then add the footer with `PdfStamper` in a second pass. Another alternative is to switch to iText 7.

Comment: Thank-you so much for your help @BrunoLowagie, I'd like to mark this as the answer as you've pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you already solve your problem based on my comments? That's great! Let's do it this way: why don't you add an answer for future reference (in case other people have the same problem) using some of the code you used (I don't know which option you chose). Tag me in a comment when you're done, and I'll up-vote it so that you get some extra reputation points.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Will do! Thank-you for your help.

Comment: Thanks, and as promised, I upvoted (both the question and the answer). Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 4):

Following @BrunoLowagie's advice, I went with the former option to create a `PageStamp` from an imported page and alter it's content as I iterated over the collection of imported PDF.

> You can keep on using `PdfCopy` and use `PageStamp` to add the text to
>   each page that is added. Or you can create the PDF in two passes:
>   first create the concatenated PDF in memory with `PdfCopy`; then add the
>   footer with `PdfStamper` in a second pass.

The reason my previous attmepts had not worked was due to the fact that,

> `PdfPageEventHelper` and `PdfCopy` are mutually exclusive. You can't
>   define a page event when using `PdfCopy` - @BrunoLowagie

The following code is an example of the preferred solution and tests have proven it to work as intended.

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, stream);                
doc.Open();
for (int x = 0, y = pages; x < y; x++)
{
    PdfImportedPage import = copy.GetImportedPage(pdf, x + 1);
    PageStamp stamp = copy.CreatePageStamp(import);
    Rectangle rect = stamp.GetUnderContent().PdfWriter.PageSize;
    ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamp.GetUnderContent(),
        Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(User.Identity.Name, font),
            (rect.Bottom + rect.Top) / 2, rect.Bottom + 8, 0);

    stamp.AlterContents();
    copy.AddPage(import);
}
```